# Difficulty returning an array of indexes of each element from an array that matches search term

Tags: arrays, function, pattern-matching, javascript

Hi I am really struggling making code for a function that 'returns an array of indexes from an already populated array containing strings, when it matches the search term'. 
So if the search term matches a word or characters in the element of the array regardless of its order, it should return the indexes in which those words are apparent in the array. Not using jquery grep feature.
Here is some code to illustrate what I mean.

```
array_test = ["Today was hot","Tomorrow will be hot aswell", "Yesterday the weather was not so good","o1234 t12345"]

function locateSearch(array_test,searchTerm){ 
var myArray = [];

for(i=0;i<array_test.length;i++){ 
if(...) // what should i be testing here, this is where i have been going wrong... 

myArray[myArray.length] = i; 
} 
 return myArray;  
}

document.write(locateSearch,'ot') //this should return indexes [0,1,2,3]
```

Sorry If I have not explained this so well, appreciate your help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
array_test = ["Today was hot","Tomorrow will be hot aswell", "Yesterday the weather was not so good","o1234 t12345"];

function locateSearch(array_test,searchTerm){
    searchTerm = searchTerm.toLowerCase();
    var myArray = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < array_test.length; i++){
        for(var j = 0; j < searchTerm.length; j++) {
            if(array_test[i].toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm[j]) >= 0) {
                myArray.push(i);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return myArray;  
}

alert(locateSearch(array_test, 'To').toString());
```

Also see this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scessor/mVXzC/3/).

=== UPDATE ===

If every char has to be in the same string:

```
array_test = ["Today was hot","Tomorrow will be hot aswell", "Yesterday the weather was not so good","o1234 t12345"];

function locateSearch(array_test,searchTerm){
    searchTerm = searchTerm.toLowerCase();
    var myArray = [];
    var bFound;
    for(var i = 0; i < array_test.length; i++){
        bFound = true;
        for(var j = 0; j < searchTerm.length; j++) {
            if(array_test[i].toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm[j]) == -1) {
                bFound = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (bFound) {
            myArray.push(i);
        }
    }
    return myArray;  
}

alert(locateSearch(array_test, 'es').toString());
```

Also see my updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scessor/mVXzC/4/).

Comment: Thanks for this. It works, but how can I make it so that if the searchterm has 'To' it returns indexes [0,2] this is what i cant i understand... thank you

Comment: Have you seen my latest version?

Comment: Hi, i was just testing with some of my data. It works well and really appreciate your time. Ive been trying different searchTerms, i tried 'es' and that should return [1,2] but it returns [0,1,2], not sure why? Thanks again, sorry to be a pain. You defintely are doing a good job of understanding my bad explanation! :)

Comment: It returns also the `0` because the `s` in the first string. Has to be all chars in the same string? I'll make an example, just a moment.

Comment: I have added an alternative solution, if every char has to be in the same string.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
array_test = ["Today was hot","Tomorrow will be hot aswell", "Yesterday the weather was not so good","o1234 t12345"]

function locateSearch(array_test,searchTerm) { 
    var myArray = [];

    for(i=0;i<array_test.length;i++) { 
        if(array_test[i].indexOf(searchTerm) != -1) // what should i be testing here, this is where i have been going wrong... 

        myArray.push(i); 
    } 
    return myArray;  
}

document.write(locateSearch,'ot') //this should return indexes [0,1,2,3]
```

This will return indexes of all elements in array_test that contain the search term.

Comment: just noticed: the last line in the code is probably not what you were looking to do. you should probably change that to document.write(locateSearch('ot').join(','))

Comment: Hey, this works great. How could I could I make it so that it finds the characters in 'array_test' no matter what order they appear in. So basically, if one element in the array has those characters in it, it should also return that index. But Thank you

Comment: if it works, please accept the answer :) I don't understand your follow-up question, maybe open a new question with more detail?

Comment: So bascially, if i enetered 'to' instead of 'ot', how could i make it return indexes, [0,1,2,3]. Because all of the elements in array_test have characters, 'to'. Hope that made sense :) thank you.

Comment: change to this bit: if(array_test[i].indexOf(searchTerm) != -1 || array_test[i].indexOf(searchTerm.reverse()) != -1) . and please accept the answer!

Answer (score 0):

if I understood your question correctly...

```
if(array_test[i].indexOf(searchTerm).toLowercase() != -1)
    myArray.push(i);
```

You didn't mention if the search was case sensitive, but assuming it is I threw it in there

Comment: indexOf returns a number, there's no reason to lower case it!  You MEANT array_test[i].toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase() )  you need to lower case both of them and compare that... or just use regEx as I suggested.

Answer (score 0):

if you need your test to be case insensitive use the regEx match method instead of indexOf()

so...  `if(array[i].match(/searchTerm/i) != null){ myArray.push(i) }`